# What should be the value of $\alpha$ for which the series is convergent?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

The series

> $$\sum \frac{\log(1+\frac{1}{n})}{n^\alpha}$$

**a.** Converges if $\alpha>0$

**b.** Diverges for all $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$

**c.** Converges if $\alpha=0$

**d.** Converges if $\alpha<0$

---

**My approach:** We know that if $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=l<1,$$ then $\sum a_n $ converges.

Here, $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{log(1+\frac{1}{n})}{n^\alpha}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{log(1+\frac{1}{n})}{\frac{1}{n}{n^{\alpha+1}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^{\alpha+1}}$

Now, if the series converges then $\displaystyle\frac{1}{n^{\alpha+1}}<1$.

but nothing can be said about $\alpha$ from this. Maybe this is not the right way to do it.

Comment: Hint:  After a while, $1/n\lt \log(1+1/n)\lt 2/n$. Or if you like Limit Comparison, the limit of $\frac{\log(1+1/n)}{1/n}$ is $1$.

Comment: The current post has a bad start. It is not true that if $\lim a_n=l\lt 1$ then $\sum a_n$ converges. Even if $\lim a_n=0$ the series need not converge.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Sorry! I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: $\log(1+\frac1n)$ behaves as $1/n$ and $\sum \frac{1}{n^\beta}$ converges for $\beta>1$. (Use the limit comparison test.)